# JavaScript Multiple Assignments to Variable

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

While working with THREE.js and Electron, I came across this statement which I don't fully understand

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(),INTERSECTED;
```

What does this syntax define in terms of the var `raycaster`? How can I use `INTERSECTED` purely from a syntactical view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line *declares* two variables and *initializes* one of them. `raycaster` has been initialized to an instance of a three-js raycaster object, while `INTERSECTED` has been declared but is `undefined` at this point.

Answer (score 1):

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var INTERSECTED;